# Javascript double alerts after onclick

Tags: javascript

I have three checkboxes in array. I handle every click of user and add value of checkbox into array. For example, page have been loaded, user have been clicked on a1, then *values* contains a1. If user clicks a1 and a3, *values* contains a1,a3 etc...

If I click into checkbox square, it works ok, but if I click on text of checkbox, js alerts two versions of array - previous(I don't need this!) and actual. Can anyone help?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/94bdepx0/

#### Markup

```
<label class="checkbox-button"><input autocomplete="off" name="tag[]" value="a1" type="checkbox">a1 text</label>
<label class="checkbox-button"><input autocomplete="off" name="tag[]" value="a2" type="checkbox">a2 text</label>
<label class="checkbox-button"><input autocomplete="off" name="tag[]" value="a3" type="checkbox">a3 text</label>
```

#### JS

```
$(".checkbox-button").bind("click", function (event) {
   var values = $("input[name='tag[]']:checked").map(function () {
       return this.value;
   }).get();
   alert(values);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
   $(".checkbox-button input").bind("click", function(event) {
       var values = $("input[name='tag[]']:checked").map(function() {
           return this.value;
       }).get();
       alert(values)
   })
```

Your problem is that you select wrong element. You should select `input` instead of the label
The updated version is here: https://jsfiddle.net/94bdepx0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your click event is bound to the label. If you bind it to the checkbox, the double alert goes away.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").bind("click", function(event) {

   var values = $("input[name='tag[]']:checked").map(function () {
            return this.value; }).get(); 
   alert(values)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listening for a 'click' on the parent element, listen for 'change' on the input itself.

```
$(".checkbox-button").bind("click", function(event) {
...
});
```

becomes:

```
$(".checkbox-button input").bind("change", function(event) {
...
});
```